Chatbot: Detect Exp. Cloud Session or Authenticate with OTP
I am working working on a requirement to implement a Chatbot that performs some actions for customers authenticated to an Experience Cloud Site, or alternatively if no active -experience-cloud session exists for that user, the user will be prompted for to enter an account id value, and we would like to send the user a OTP (One-Time Password) and have them enter it in the Chatbot, and receive an authenticated session to access data in Salesforce.
Is this scenario possible in Salesforce Chatbots? I cannot find a documented flow of doing so?

